# Is it possible to boot my desktop using the OS installed on my laptop and use the desktop as if it were my laptop?

Tags: boot

I have a desktop running on Ubuntu and a laptop running on Windows 10. Both the machines are connected to the same network. Is it possible to boot my desktop using Win10 installed on my laptop and access all the applications and files installed on the laptop? Can I achieve this using PXE or PXE is just for installing an OS from the network?

Comment: If you just plug in the harddisk of your laptop in your computer, it may be that it works, but windows may change config files in order to make booting possible. That may break ubuntu and it may break any ability to get it back in your laptop. You can however use disk2vhd to create a vhd image of your disk, then use something like VirtualBox to load your laptop safely inside a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

It is *very unlikely* that switching hard drives from a laptop to a desktop, or *vice versa*, would work immediately because different hardware drivers are needed. If you *were* to force the issue, drivers might be installed that would then *disable* use of the HDD on the original machine.

However, you can [use Remote Desktop between Linux and Windows](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/connecting-windows-remote-desktop-ubuntu/), if your version of Windows supports it.

- [Enable Remote Access](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-allow-access) on the Windows PC.
- [Install Remmina](https://www.tecmint.com/remmina-remote-desktop-sharing-and-ssh-client/), if it is not already installed.
- Configure and establish a connections between PC's.

Now, for all practical purposes, you can use all the Windows software and data *from Ubuntu* as if you were on the Windows PC, and once setup is completed, you can connect and disconnect in a few seconds. You can also [transfer files](https://www.net-usb.com/usb-over-rdp/remote-dekstop-copy-files/) between machines with RDP.